# stringResource vs LocalContext.current.getString in compose Android

Tags: android, performance, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-textfield

I have created a sample app and found that when I used stringresource to fetch the string, the composable function was called two times and In the case of LocalContext.current.getString composable function was called one time. I also tested with localization in both cases it's working. When I scanned the stringresource function internally it uses a resource composable function and it was mentioned A composable function that returns the Resources. **It will be recomposed when Configuration gets updated.**
But if Configuration is not changed then how come it recomposes the composable function mentioned in example?

**Sample Code stringresource**

```
@Composable
fun ComposableTestWithStringResource() {
Log.d(TAG, "ComposableTestWithStringResource")

Text(
    text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name),
)
}
```

**Sample Code LocalContext.current.getString**

```
@Composable
fun ComposableTestWithLocalContextString() {
Log.d(TAG, "ComposableTestWithStringResource")

Text(
    text =  LocalContext.current.getString(R.string.app_name),
)
}
```

Comment: Found the same issue, really strange behavior. If I use `stringResource` there is one more recomposition after initial composiiton.

Comment: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior), https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/239060887#comment3